# Minimum Swaps required to bring all the number greater than or equal to K together

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of **N** numbers and a number **K**. Find the minimum number of swaps required to bring all the numbers **greater than or equal** to **K** together.

**Input Format:**

First line contains an integer N, denoting the number of elements in the array

Second line contains N space-separated integers, denoting the elements of an array.

```
Sample Input:                                  Sample Output:
5 3                                            1
5 2 1 3 4
```

Comment: Please explain the example: does output 1 mean that there is a single swap that brings 4 and 5 together? What have you done to solve this? Any effort?

Comment: @trincot: I'm guessing the swap is with `5` and `1` bringing `5 3 4` "together".

Comment: @trincot: for the given example, K=3. So, you can swap 1 and 5  to segregate (bring together) 5 3 4 with minimum swaps.

Comment: OK, and what about my second & third question?

Comment: @trincot: My approach is first to check all number greater than equal to K. i.e 5,3,4 and now represent every number as binary , where 0 is for numbers less than K and 1 for numbers greater than K. So, for above array, I have binary representation like 10011. Finally, compare it with 00111

Comment: OK, so then the question is to determine the number of swaps to bring the 1s together. Did you do anything for that?

Comment: @trincot: let say we are comparing 10011 and 00111 string. So, just count where ith char one string is not equal to ith char of other (i.e 1 & 0 case). And finally, the answer is count/2.

Comment: @RohitSroch: Your step 1 leads to "10031".

Comment: @userunknown: represent every number as binary, where 0 is for numbers less than K and 1 for numbers greater than equal to K. so, step 1 leads to 10011.

Comment: @RohitSroch: Don't refine your question in the comments, but edit the question.

Comment: So, what's the problem then ? Have you implemented Your Approach, if yes  then show.

Comment: This question is asked from a live contest on HackerEarth, [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/hiring/pramata-software-engineer-hiring-challenge/problems/0af5df099c344c409da2efd9bddfc8b4/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

- Count the number of values >= K, call it C
- Count how many values are < K in the first C elements of the array: this represents the number of values to be swapped if we aim to group all values >= K at the far left of the array
- Drop the left most value from that window and add the next one at the right of it, keeping the window size at C. Adjust the number of swaps accordingly.
- Keep moving the window to the right and keep track what was the minimum number of swaps in any of these configurations.

Here is an interactive implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function solve(a, k) {
    let count, i, swaps, leastSwaps;
    // 1. Count number of elements >= k:
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] >= k) count++;
    }
    // 2. Count number of elements < k in first "window": 
    //    These would need to be swapped.
    swaps = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (a[i] < k) swaps++;
    }
    leastSwaps = swaps;
    // 3. Slide window to the right minimising number of swaps
    for (i = 0; i < a.length - count; i++) {
        if (a[i] < k) swaps--;
        if (a[i+count] < k) swaps++;
        if (swaps < leastSwaps) leastSwaps = swaps;
    }
    return leastSwaps;
}


// I/O management
function process() {
    const a = arrayInput.value.match(/\d+/g).map(Number),
        k = +pivotInput.value;
    result.textContent = solve(a, k);
}

arrayInput.oninput = pivotInput.oninput = process;
// Launch on page load
process();
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>Numbers:</td><td><input id="arrayInput" size="40" value="5 2 1 3 4" ></td></tr>
    <tr><td>K:</td><td><input id="pivotInput" size="4" value="3"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Swaps:</td><td><span id="result">?</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is already correct but I would like to provide the logic for why that program works:
**Underline principle:** minimum swaps will be required in the smallest subarray where maximum number of elements greater than or equal to k are present.

**What should be the size of smallest subarray?** that should be the total no of elements greater than or equal to k. It makes sense because suppose all the elements greater than or equal to k are together, your subarray size cannot be smaller than this.

Within the given array whichever subarray has minimum no of elements violating the condition is our subarray and the no of elements violating the condition is the answer because these violations needs to be swapped with correct ones

Answer (score 0):

Find count of all elements which are less than or equals to ‘k’. Let’s say the count is ‘cnt’
Using two pointer technique for window of length ‘cnt’, each time keep track of how many elements in this range are greater than ‘k’. Let’s say the total count is ‘var1’.
Repeat step 2, for every window of length ‘cnt’ and take minimum of count ‘var1’ among them. This will be the final answer.